# send USSD code to D-link GSM modem

Tags: linux, gsm, at-command, ussd

I have a D-Link DWM-157 GSM Modem. It is connected to a USB port and it seems working. I can use minicom and miniterm.py to set the right port (i.e. /dev/ttyUSB0) and can get OK for AT and ATZ commands. The problem is that I don't get any response when I run USSD codes. The following is the output of miniterm.py:

```
--- Available ports:
---  1: /dev/ttyUSB0         'D-Link DWM-157'
---  2: /dev/ttyUSB1         'D-Link DWM-157'
---  3: /dev/ttyUSB2         'D-Link DWM-157'
---  4: /dev/ttyUSB3         'D-Link DWM-157'
--- Enter port index or full name: 1
--- Miniterm on /dev/ttyUSB0  9600,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
AT

OK
ATZ

OK
AT+CUSD=1,"*140*11#"

OK
```

and then no response! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this apply for any ussd values, or have you tried something other than 140?

Comment: Honestly, The problem has been solved. But I do not know how did it get solved!! I just took out the SIM card from GSM modem and put it into my phone and sent the USSD code *140*11# via my phone. After that I could get the answer but it was in HEX. I put the SIM card again into my phone and changed the language to English (which was Persian at first), and now I can get the result correctly.